# How to publish application in my environment that created in other environment

Tags: outsystems

I want publish one application which is created in another environment. When I publish application it gives following error

Foreign Module Error

"Your OutSystems subscription only allows uploading modules developed in your environment, or downloaded from the OutSystems Forge. To share this module with the community, upload it at http://www.outsystems.com/goto/forge."

What I do because I want publish without uploading on forge please help me..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to the vendor. The error message clearly indicates it's an issue with the particular subscription (version) you're using. It's a product support question related to your license for the product, and should be addressed to the vendor directly through their support or sales staff. (We're neither of those things.)

Comment: Pedantic^2 there Ken. Sure they need to contact the vendor, but the issue is one almost all Outsystems users face at some point and the answer needs to be readily available, which posts like these help to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact OutSystems support as Ken indicated.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, your application intellectual property rights are protected.

[You can read more about it at the vendor site.](https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Licensing/Intellectual_Property_Protection_(IPP)/01_What_is_IPP_(Intellectual_Property_Protection))